# distro for linux kernel development

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Which is the best light weight distro for learning linux kernel development. It should have lot of debugging and profiling tools available along with it :)

Answer (score 9):

[LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). Then install every debugger and profiler you can find.

Comment: I can use all of those and they are cool, but it takes a lot of time for patching, testing, etc.

Comment: Also have a look at Buildroot, which automates everything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625382/895245

Answer (score 8):

I've heard [Linus himself uses Fedora](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/geek-of-the-week/linus-torvalds,-geek-of-the-week/). I'd recommend [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) which lets (intends) for you to hand customize your kernel, it's the perfect setting for it (and I've spent many hours squeezing out every last bit of performance for the fun of it).

Naturally [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is my preferred distro, but you may have trouble if you start hijacking and removing expected kernel features. Gentoo won't complain, and doesn't expected them around to begin with.

Comment: The Ubuntu kernel carries a fair number of patches for things like UUID handling and other such magic. I run vanilla kernels on my gentoo box all the time without problems.

Comment: Fedora is also my favorite, damn stable.

Answer (score 7):

I've enjoyed using [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) for fiddling around with the kernel.

Comment: Another vote for Gentoo.

Answer (score 4):

The distro does not really matter.  It is what you want to do with the kernel and do development/testing its feature.

Here are few things to do.

a. Turn on the kernel debugging and the logging options.  Those would definitely help you in debugging.
see [useful linux kernel debug options to turn on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475369/useful-linux-kernel-debug-options-to-turn-on)

b. Getdebuggers tool like Valgrind that checks for memory leak.  See doc like https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kmemleak.txt

c. Found a good editor for editing. I don't want to start a vim vs emacs war.  It is really a personal preference, just make sure you follow the linux kernel coding style guidelines. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle‎

d. Get familiar with the log systems and proc system, as they provide valuable information.

e. Read the documentation in the directory /usr/src/linux/Documentation Very good starting point to understand the kernel

Answer (score 2):

The distro probably doesn't make much difference since you'll be working on your own kernel and not the "kitchen sink" kernel the distros tend to provide with a bunch of patches in most cases.

If you're doing kernel development work then I suppose you want a distro that boots quickly, something like puppy might be ideal here and do your actual coding from something like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**Buildroot**

[Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) is a set of scripts that generates tiny distros with rootfs images smaller than 10MiB.

It downloads everything from source and compiles it, so it is trivial to patch packages up.

The generated images are so tiny, that it becomes possible to understand the entire userland setup, which will make it easier to focus on the kernel.

Advantage over LFS: everything is fully automated. Because of this, Buildroot is used professionally in large organizations.

I have created this setup to automate things as much as possible: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat